# IIS Pass Through Authentication Using App Pool Account

Tags: iis

In IIS 8, I have disabled Anonymous Authentication so that the user domain identity is passed through to IIS. This allows my application to identify the user and set internal application security appropriately.

I would, however, like the user to still run under the App Pool account to access local resources. Is this possible?

Here are my currents settings

[image: IIS Settings]

Comment: You'd better show some of your IIS configuration, so that people can see what you meant above (in case you didn't configure the proper settings). Besides, try to see if you can understand the different identities (process/thread), https://blog.lextudio.com/the-basic-facts-about-iis-asp-net-process-thread-identities-835eaac876a0 In most cases, IIS still uses the application pool identity to access local/remote resources, unless you (or the web framework you use) enable impersonation.

Comment: Turning off impersonation no longer passes through the user domain identity. What I want is the identity passed through to IIS but the user running under the app pool account.

Comment: Add the domain user in User or Group policy so that it can pass through windows authentication. Then disable impersonation. Domain user can pass through windows authentication and application still run under app pool identity.